# MyBatis variable with binded null is not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mybatis

MyBatis 3.2.8. I have the following code in select:

```
<bind name="groupDir" value="references.get('groupDir')" />
<if test="groupDir!=null">
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ......
</if>
```

Everything is ok when `groupDir!=null`. However, when `groupDir==null` I get the following exception:

> Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
>
> ### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'groupDir' not
>   found. Available parameters are [filterRules, sorterRules, param5,
>   references, columns, param3, param4, param1, param2, limitRule]
>
> ###  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'groupDir' not found. Available parameters are [filterRules,
>   sorterRules, param5, references, columns, param3, param4, param1,
>   param2, limitRule]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I haven't used binds so I might be wrong, but can you make the bind conditional on groupDir!=null? Use an <if> or <choose><when> to avoid the problematic statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug and now it's fixed. https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/343